# Try and except, the program should continue where it left of

Tags: python, pandas

Ok, so i have a code in pandas and i need help with making the try and except work. Basically if the user writes the index name with lowercase on the first, secound or last question it should give a KeyError, but in except: i need to somehow make it so that the program takes care of the problem.

By taking care i mean it should set the dataframe index values to lowercase and then go back to try and continue where it left of.

I provide the part of code that i think is necessary. The program asks the user to write a name of a municipality and it prints out the maximun tax that they got with corresponding year.

i tried to write in except to solve it but it doesnt work. Im doing it wrong and i cant solve it by myself. i appreciate the help i can get here. thanks alot!

```py
def resultat_maxmin(dfexcel,dfcsv):
    try:

        first = str(input("write the name: "))

        series = dfexcel.loc[first].astype(int)
        print("In", first ," they had the max taxincome", serie1.max(),"dollar year ",series.idxmax(axis=1),"\n")
    except KeyError:
        dfexcel.index = dfexcel.index.str.lower()
```

Comment: the dfexcel has index values starting with each row with uppercase and rest is lower. And no i dont want to set it all to lowercase before, i need the try and except to solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: you can convert first char to upper using `first[0].upper() + first[1:]` or try `first.title()` or `first.capitalize()`

Comment: you can add this in `try` to reduce chance to get exception.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to set it all to lowercase before? That would be the best way to do it.

Otherwise, you can call the function itself in the `except` block like this:

```
    except KeyError:
        dfexcel.index = dfexcel.index.str.lower()
        resultat_maxmin(dfexcel,dfcsv)
```

Comment: this method would ask the questions again, thanks tho